# REDCap calculated fields for repeated instruments

Tags: redcap

I have a question (checkbox) that is Checkboxes question in a instrument that is repeatable (repeater).

I am trying to get the max value selected across all instances for each record.

When using the following syntax in the descriptive field and piping the data, this works and provides the value of "checkbox" in instance 1 and the "checkbox" in instance 2

```
[checkbox:1]
[checkbox:2]
```

When I try to do this in a calculated field as shown below. I get an error. I believe it does not like the colon in the syntax.

```
max([checkbox:1],[checkbox:2])
```

Any Ideas on how I can achieve this?